# How to pass a String-to-String mapping into a Drools session

Tags: java, drools

I have Drools rules that insert values into a database. I want to give the session a mapping of String values I have to String values that should be written. So in my Java file, something like this:

```
StatefulKnowledgeSession session = ...    
Map<String, String> stateToPostalCode = new HashMap<>();
stateToPostalCode.insert("Texas", "TX");
stateToPostalCode.insert("New Jersey", "NJ");
....
session.insert(stateToPostalCode);
```

Then my rules could convert states to postal codes.

But inserting it doesn't work. I get a stack trace and a complaint of

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Boolean

Inserts of `Map<String, Integer>` work, but not `Map<String, String>`. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: It's possible that you aren't using the Map correctly in your rule(s). You'll have to add them to your Q for a better diagnosis.

Comment: What kind of Map/HashMap are you using? I can't see the insert() method in my JDK7/JDK8 implementation.

Comment: The session is a drools StatefulKnowledgeSession. I am trying to insert the map to the session so my rules can use it. I can't get as far as inserting the map, so it doesn't matter what the rules say.

Comment: PLEASE POST THE RULE CODE. A FAILURE LIKE THIS, DURING INSERT, IS USUALLY DUE TO INCORRECT RULE CODE. (Hint: adding @xyz alerts user xyz, so you don't lose time.)

Comment: -1 due to not providing relevant information when asking a question.

Comment: @laune, you were correct. I fixed the rule syntax (noted below).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the rule fixed the problem. Here is the correct syntax.

```
when
...        
   $map : Map($value: this["Texas"])
```

Comment: I don't want to disappoint you, but I don't think that this is going to be a durable solution. Depending on the Drools version, you may not be able to use a previously bound variable in place of a String literal. And you may have to guard against the key not being in the map, or spelled differently... Well, good luck.